# No write access

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, production-environment, readonly

I’m writing SQL queries in the snowflake production environment and I have “READ ONlY ACCESS”. so I'm not able to create temp table/CTE or write subqueries. so I had to do most of the work manually in excel.  What alternative can be used to fix this problem?

Comment: What kind of error are you receiving? CTE/suqbuery is part of a standard query so if it possible to write a standard query cte is also feasible. [Creating a Temporary Table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#creating-a-temporary-table) "Note that creating a temporary table does not require the CREATE TABLE privilege on the schema in which the object is created."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have usage privileges on Database, Schema and read privileges on the table, then only you can create a temporary table via select query.

Also, you need WH to execute the command.

Example

```
create or replace role testrole12;
GRANT usage ON WAREHOUSE SUJAN_WH to 
role testrole12;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE SAMPLEDATABASE 
to role testrole12;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA 
SAMPLEDATABASE.TEST to role testrole12;
GRANT SELECT ON 
SAMPLEDATABASE.TEST.MYCSVTABLE to role 
testrole12;
GRANT role testrole12 to user sujanT3;
```

Now login with user sujanT3 and use role testrole12

```
create or replace temporary table temp 
as 
select * from mycsvtable;
```

Please try.

Regards,
Sujan